# OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() works only for once

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a application which toast the word you copied to the clipboard in a WebView for practice. The problem is, this code works for the first word(except somehow it toasts for three times. Sort of blink.); however, when I try to copy a word for the second time, it shows 
`"Unfortunately, (my app's name) has stopped"`
and stop working. It still shows the website, but the toast function stops. I'm running this program on an emulator and using Eclipse. Following Mr/Ms.jgriffsta's advise, I added a try&catch statement, then for the second time it toasts "Error occured" once, and then toasts the copied word for two times. Again sort of blink.

```
//ItemDetailActivity.java
public class ItemDetailActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView mWeb;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.item_detail);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String link = intent.getStringExtra("LINK");
        mWeb = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
        mWeb.loadUrl(link);

        final ClipboardManager cm = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        cm.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new OnPrimaryClipChangedListener(){
            @Override
            public void onPrimaryClipChanged(){
                ClipData.Item item = cm.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0);
                String text = item.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

----LogCat--------

```
07-18 18:15:07.530: E/chromium(837): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(153)] No suitable EGL configs found.
07-18 18:15:07.540: E/chromium(837): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(620)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
07-18 18:15:07.540: E/chromium(837): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(153)] No suitable EGL configs found.
07-18 18:15:07.540: E/chromium(837): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(620)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
07-18 18:15:07.540: E/chromium(837): [ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(86)] gfx::GLSurface::InitializeOneOff() failed
07-18 18:15:10.360: E/chromium(837): [ERROR:simple_backend_impl.cc(186)] File structure does not match the disk cache backend.
07-18 18:15:10.360: E/chromium(837): [ERROR:simple_backend_impl.cc(402)] Simple Cache Backend: wrong file structure on disk: /data/data/com.kariga.rssreader1/app_webview/Cache
07-18 18:16:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(837): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-18 18:16:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(837): Process: com.kariga.rssreader1, PID: 837
07-18 18:16:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(837): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-18 18:16:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at com.kariga.rssreader1.ItemDetailActivity$1.onPrimaryClipChanged(ItemDetailActivity.java:34)
07-18 18:16:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.content.ClipboardManager.reportPrimaryClipChanged(ClipboardManager.java:234)
07-18 18:16:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.content.ClipboardManager$2.handleMessage(ClipboardManager.java:76)
07-18 18:16:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-18 18:16:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-18 18:16:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-18 18:16:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 18:16:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-18 18:16:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-18 18:16:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-18 18:16:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

----Edited Code with Try&Catch Statement--------

```
final ClipboardManager cm = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
cm.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new OnPrimaryClipChangedListener(){
    @Override
    public void onPrimaryClipChanged(){
        ClipData.Item item = cm.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0);
        try{String text = item.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

----LogCat after edition--------

```
07-18 18:57:28.780: E/chromium(882): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(153)] No suitable EGL configs found.
07-18 18:57:28.780: E/chromium(882): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(620)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
07-18 18:57:28.790: E/chromium(882): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(153)] No suitable EGL configs found.
07-18 18:57:28.790: E/chromium(882): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(620)]  GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
07-18 18:57:28.790: E/chromium(882): [ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(86)] gfx::GLSurface::InitializeOneOff() failed
```

Answer (score 0):

(Would Put this as comment if I could)

You don't check for any exceptions, so I would put a try, catch statment on

```
String text = item.getText().toString();
```

Could you post the error report to the logcat. It should point out the exact reason.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! I added the report in the logcat. It seems like I have another problem in the file structure, too? Anyways, I will write the try&catch statement.